# Media Player no reproduce audio desde url [Android]

Tags: android, stream, mediaplayer

Estoy intentando reproducir audio desde una una url que emite audio pero cuado le paso la url  a Media Player no la reproduce, pero en el navegagor si funciona.

Permisos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Mi codigo:

```
String url = "http://n13.radiojar.com/5705c71sn2zuv?rj-ttl=5&rj-tok=AAABhPz0EysAQfb4iRmp2q_BTQ";

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder().setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC).build());
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        // prepare async to not block main thread
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        //start audio
        mediaPlayer.start
```

Comment: Revisa que muestra el LogCat al tratar de reproducir.

Comment: No dice nada , es como si no reconociera la url, pero otras urls si las preproduce, y como dice la publicacion esa url que tiene el steam se reproduce sin problemas en la web.